# Automating requests on a website

Tags: java, python, c++, scripting

I basically need to send testimonial requests to all my friends in class on [this site](http://lcnitd.com/yearbook/2014/). This is what the page looks like(after logging in):

[image]

I need to enter the roll number in the textbox one by one which I want to automate by a script probably by running a loop over all the roll numbers. The roll numbers are of the form 10/CSE/XX with XX in range(1, 92). How do I do it?
This is the specific part from the html source.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="span9">
            <h2>Request New Testimonial</h2>
            <form name="request" action="requesttestimonial.php" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="requestroll" placeholder="Roll number of the person you want to request a testimonial" />
                <input type="submit" value="Send Request" name="submitrequest" />
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The login page:

```
        <form class="navbar-form pull-right" method="POST" action="login.php">
          <input class="span2" name="rollnumber" type="text" placeholder="Roll Number">
          <input class="span2" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
          <button type="submit" class="btn" name="signin">Sign in</button>
        </form>
```

Any language would do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used twill from python and this made the job more simpler than I could ever imagine, here is the code:

```
from twill.commands import go, fv, submit
go('http://lcnitd.com/yearbook/2014/index.php')
fv("2","rollnumber","10/CSE/2")
fv("2","password","myPassword")
submit('0')
go('http://www.lcnitd.com/yearbook/2014/request.php')
n=1
roll="10/CSE/"
while(n<100):
    sleep(2)
    temp=roll+`n`
    print n
    fv("2","requestroll",temp)
    n+=1
    submit('0')
```

`showforms()` can be used to see the forms on a page and `formclear()` can be used to clear a form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java's Selenium package. It is simple and supports a wide variety of HTML controls, unless you were looking for something python specific, in which case ignore my answer

EDIT:

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Example taken from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted , which is just about enough for what you need

Comment: I am new to it so it would be great if you could post some sample code  to show me how it works.

Comment: Editing now to include one

Comment: The website has a login too.. I could get it working for google but not for my site.. :(

Comment: that can be done too! just select the html element and do sendKeys(username), select the password html element and do sendKeys(password), then select the login button and do .click()

Comment: I am accepting your answer but I ended up using something else... See my answer. I think its amazingly simple and works! Thanks for giving me an insight!

Comment: seems quite simple, though I am not very familiar with python. However, Selenium offers more maintainability through the use of Page Objects. Also, it can be combined with Cucumber to utilise Behaviour Driven Development http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/a-automating-ria/index.html